# shift key in windows 8.1 is typing other characters instead of 'shift'

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard

A customer keyboard 'left shift' and 'right shift' keys are not working as a shift key. I checked the registry and there's no remap for those keys. This is what happens when I click shift. Those logs are from the software keyscancodes

```
OnKeyDown, Key code=20, Control keys=, Key name CAPS LOCK
OnKeyDown, Key code=114, Control keys=, Key name F3
OnKeyDown, Key code=83, Control keys=, Key name s
OnKeyPress s
OnKeyup, Key code=20, Control keys=, Key name CAPS LOCK

OnKeyup, Key code=114, Control keys=, Key name F3

OnKeyup, Key code=83, Control keys=, Key name s
```

This is really messed up, right? The 'right shift' key is also messed up. The virtual keyboard shift keys from windows are working, maybe because the scancode is different. 
The computer is a dell laptop. The problem started yesterday.
ideas on how to fix this?

thx

Comment: Is "sticky keys" enabled?

Comment: no, they are not enabled

Comment: Have you tried plugging in an external keyboard? That would narrow the issue to either the physical keyboard and connector or to software.

Comment: Both left and right shift has the same behavior but are throwing different codes, I think it's not a hardware issue, since the scancode and signal for both differs, also the hw connectors in the mboard are different for each key. Do you agree? Trying a new keyboard is a good test, thx for your suggestion, but now I would like to focus on understanding

Comment: So when you press the shift keys (left or right), the `CAPS LOCK`, `F3` and `S` keys are "pressed" instead? So, if you opened notepad and pressed `SHIFT`, the `CAPS` light would come on, a capital `S` would be printed and a search would be redone (`F3` in notepad is the shortcut for 'search again') ... or is it that the scan codes being reported are just different than what is expected?

Comment: Yes and no. The left shift key will do everything you said, the right shift key will "press" different keys, no CAPS LOCK for instance